# iPhone 5 Simulator not letterboxing, white bar instead

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios-simulator, iphone-5

I have two apps that I'm testing on the iPhone 5 simulator. Both of which are going to be released before they are updated to handle the new resolution of the iPhone 5. My first app letterboxes nicely in the simulator with black bars at the bottom and top. The other app however, doesn't letter box, instead it has one large white bar that is the equivalent height of both black bars on a properly functioning app.
I have removed the "auto added" -586@2x.png file. I've also unchecked "autoresize subviews" check box on all my views (this is how I go the first app to letterbox properly). I'm at a loss as to what is different. I've checked all the project settings and they look identical between the two apps. I've done a clean build, I've deleted the app out of the simulator to force a fresh copy. Nothing has fixed my issue. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved my problem, as it turned out it was an error on my part, I had the simulator set to Retina 4 inch and iOS 6, but had iPhone 5.0 Simulator selected in XCode for debugging. Once I set it to iPhone 6.0 Simulator, it came up letterboxed properly.

Comment: Interesting. I am having the same problem but don't have the iPhone 5.0 Simulator installed (only 6.0).